# Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Mac

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, java-9

Estoy probando levantar una aplicación web con un servidor apache tomcat. Pero al iniciar el server, arroja en la consola siguiente mensaje.

> -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Users/nicolas/Documents/apache-tomcat-8.0.51/endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
>   in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.
>
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: con otra aplicación dice lo mismo?

Comment: sí, muestra ese mensaje cada vez que le doy start al server

Comment: si otras apps java andan fuera del tomcat, puede ser que el tomcat no encuentre el java (revisar las variables de entorno) o que le falle algo tipo la memoria (pero segun recuerdo si es memoria avisa onda insufficient memory)

Comment: No es por aplicaciones, pasa cada vez que le doy start al server. Como es eso de las variables de entorno?

Comment: Por el tag de tu pregunta, veo que tienes jdk 9, y tu version de tomcat es 8, en el detail de tomcat menciona; Tomcat 8.0 was designed to run on Java SE 7.

Comment: Cuando quiero ejecutar un apache tomcat 9.0 también arroja el mismo error

Comment: Finalmente llegué a un foro de eclipse donde decía que la versión 9 de java aun no es compatible con apache tomcat. Eliminé completamente java de mi terminal y luego instalé la versión 8. desde ahí no tuve más problemas

Comment: Si lo usas con Eclipse, el bug ya está corregido: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=507338